# PHP string to mason JS option

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass a PHP string to javascript and then use it as an option. I am using the `http://masonjs.com/` docs to do this. When I use the `data` variable it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mason;
    var size;
    var data = "<?php echo $this->getSizes($blocks); ?>";
    console.log(data);
    //This contains: [3,2],[2,2]

    jQuery(function(){
        mason = jQuery("#grid").mason({
            itemSelector: ".masonblock",
            ratio: 1.5,
            sizes:[
                data
            ],
            columns: [
                [0, 480, 6]
            ],
            filler: {
                itemSelector: '.filler',
                filler_class: 'mason-filler'
            },
            gutter: 5,
            layout: "fluid"
        })
    });
</script>
```

The data variable contains `[3,2],[2,2]` which is what I wanted to achieve but it does not work. However, if I copy this same value from the console.log and paste it directly in the sizes options it will work.

I tried doing this as well but it adds a double quote outside the option:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($this->getSizes($blocks)); ?>;
//Ends up as: "[3,2],[2,2]"
```

It appears that it has something to do with the type of string being passed as the option. Should I be sending the value as an object? Can you show me what I am doing wrong?

I even tried `JSON.stringify(data);` but no joy.

Comment: Try `data = [<?php echo $this->getSizes($blocks); ?>];` and give sizes option as `sizes: data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var data = JSON.parse("[" + <?php echo json_encode($this->getSizes($blocks)); ?> + "]");
```

"[3,2],[2,2]" isn't a valid JSON string. You need to enclose it in an array for `JSON.parse()` to work.

Note: `data` will have the value `[[3,2],[2,2]]` so you may want to change `sizes: [data]` to just `sizes: data`.

Comment: Can you tell me if I were to send it as an php array how I can convert it to the sizes options?

Comment: @MagentoMan When passing data from PHP to the front end you are dealing with strings, you can't pass PHP objects. However, you can pass JSON encoded PHP objects and then decode them in into JavaScript objects. So, in a one liner `sizes: JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($your_php_array) ?>);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($this->getSizes($blocks)); ?>);
```

Should do the trick. Although consider is bad practice generating JS from PHP

Answer (score 0):

That plugin you are using expects `sizes` to be an array. When you write:

```
var data = "<?php echo $this->getSizes($blocks); ?>";
```

This will be printed as:

```
var data = "[3,2],[2,2]"; // Will be a string not an array
```

BUT

```
var data = [<?php echo $this->getSizes($blocks); ?>]; // I removed quotes plus added brackets to make it an array
```

and you call yo plugin as......

```
jQuery(function(){
    mason = jQuery("#grid").mason({
        itemSelector: ".masonblock",
        ratio: 1.5,
        sizes: data,
        ......
    });
});
```